# Creating Bubble chart from a dictionary of arrays using d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a dictionary of 4 arrays. I want to create a bubble chart with this data.
My data `jobdata[0]` is as below:

```
Agriculture:
(10) ["10.18200016", "1.947999954", "18.35700035", "2.871999979", "1.307999969", "43.44400024", "3.884000063", "3.502000093", "1.123999953", "1.659999967"]
Industry:
(10) ["20.86899948", "19.51300049", "26.79100037", "20.29400063", "27.38199997", "23.71999931", "26.12199974", "25.61499977", "18.45800018", "18.79100037"]
Service:
(10) ["68.9489975", "78.53900146", "54.85200119", "76.83399963", "71.30999756", "32.83499908", "69.99299622", "70.88300323", "80.41899872", "79.5490036"]
country_name:
(10) ["Brazil", "Canada", "China", "France", "Germany", "India", "Italy", "Japan", "United Kingdom", "United States"]
```

and here is my code:

```
var xScale = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .domain(jobdata[0].country_name)
    .range([10,210,410,610,810,1010,1210,1410,1610,1810]);
    var bottomAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale);
    var chartGroup = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top}))
    .call(bottomAxis);

var circle = chartGroup.selectAll('circle')
    .data(jobdata[0])
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("cx",d=>xScale(d.country_name))
    .attr("cy", 50)
    .attr("r", d=>d.Agriculture)
    .attr("stroke", "black")
    .attr("stroke-width", "2")
    .attr("fill", "blue");
```

Comment: Please add to your question what you already tried and what failed. Just giving code and expecting the community to give you an answer is not enough.

Comment: The above code is what I tried. I printed out all the arrays individually as well as the entire dictionary and it is printing it correctly. The ScaleOrdinal function is working. I am able to show the x-axis with the country names. Just the circles are not showing up. basically the binding of the data doesn't seem to be working